# ASP.NET Web API Own Response Code Pattern Suggestion

Tags: asp.net, webapi, error-code, http-response-codes

In the case of a data validation error, I want to return HTTP status code 200 (OK) with my own error code.

Following is my sample error response JSON.

HttpStatusCode : 200
Response JSON

```
{  
  "isError": true,  
  "resultInfo": {  
    "resultCode": "801",  
    "resultMessage": "Order(s)-RNSIN000001 is already exists!!"  
  },  
  "orderStatus": null  
}
```

**Can I go with this pattern or It will be a violation of the API response pattern?**

Comment: For whatever is worth I never return anything other than 200OK from my apis.... I always return an object with a property called success and some error property and a content property.  That way i never have to use http status codes or exceptions for control flow which i think is way worse than violating the "api response pattern"